# My wordpress site was hacked. Many strange Chinese HTMLs and Scripts. Can't log into WP

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, virus

My WordPress website has been blocked by my FTP administrator. The reason is some spam script that occured. It causes that there is a ton of strange Chinese htmls followed by weird php and javascript files. 
Basically it looks like this.

[image: my wp-admin/maint]

[image: wp-includes (few thousand of these files)]

Maybe someone did see this kind of virus before.

Comment: Seems like a similar advertisement payload as I've seen on a WordPress website two months ago. In that case it was the WordPress theme which had a (intentional or unintentional) security issue, which attackers used. Can you show us your HTTP (for example Apache) log? (with IP-addresses removed)

Comment: Delete your wordpress installation, set it up again or restore from earlier backup (check that your backup isn't compromised). Keep your WP up-to-date in the future.

Comment: You can upload fresh wp-admin and wp-includes folder. after that you can search in themes and folders that what actually effected by hacking or virus, remove that code and place proper code.

Comment: Though if you are not sure how to do it, hire professional WordPress expert who can help you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress is a massive target for bots that search for known vulnerabilities in plugins and third party scripts such as themes or any additional changes. I've had many associates and clients have their sites compromised. Wordpress cant go through all the plugins and themes that are uploaded to the showcase and do a full extensive vulnerability assessment on them.

Your best bet is to find what the cause of the breach is which is most likely going to be a theme or plugin and not the wordpress core or a server issue by checking the apache access_log and see what files are being accessed around the time before the breach.

Disabling and deleting the plugins and themes that are causing the issues may not fully resolve your problems. You may need to reset all passwords, change all keys in the config files and send an email to all users informing them of the situation so they can reset their passwords.

Lastly, you could go through and try delete the files that seem to be the cause of the issues based off creation date, but you may miss some files. I would suggest just doing a fresh re-install with your required plugins and swap your database and uploads to your new site.